# Eclipse External Tool Configuration - separate button on toolbar for a specific configuration

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to create an External Tool Configuraion for running an external tool and assign it to a separate button on a Toolbar? When I use two different External Tool Configurations, I have to select from dropdown menu and that's not perfect. I use Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own plugin for this there is no other way.

You can call the external program launch configurations by keyboard.
Assign keyboard short cut key for `External Tools..` command as shown here. I assigne <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

[image]

When you press this key then below dialog will popup.

[image]

Type the name of external configuration to filter, when your configuration is selected in the tree then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to launch the program.

---

### Other way

Click on dropdown button of the `Run external tool` button then you will get the below menu.

[image]

You can press the corresponding number assigned to each launch configuration. In the picture shown above when you press **3** then `tmp` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RAD, there exists a separate button in the toolbar for external tools.  [image]